# Registering ContentObserver for Android CallLog causes crash

Tags: android, securityexception, contentobserver, calllog

Recently my app keeps crashing when registering a contentObserver for the Android CallLog (in `onCreate` of a `Service`). This is the way I register it:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true, new MyObserver(new Handler()));
```

*Part of the stacktrace:*

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service
>   nl.xelion.restandroid.service.CallLogChanged:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from
>   ProcessRecord{f73a1ed 7949:nl.my.app.debug/u0a119}
>   (pid=7949, uid=10119) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider...etc

I used this tutorial, and it DID work for about a year:
http://www.adityathakker.com/android-content-observer-react-on-content-change

Approximately since Android O the crashes started to appear. The javadoc of `registerContentObserver` does say something along these lines: `Starting in O, all content notifications must be backed by a valid ContentProvider.` So I was wondering if this would be the problem, and if so, how to solve it?

<s>Anyway, why is it complaining about permissions for contacts, and</s> why didn't this happen before? This doesn't make sense to me.

<s>ps. I do use code which requires permission for contacts, which is called in the onChange of the ContentObserver, but even when I comment this piece of code the crash still occurs.</s>

Comment: "So I was wondering if this would be the problem" -- I doubt it, given the error message. "why is it complaining about permissions for contacts" -- it is complaining about permissions for the call log (`READ_CALL_LOG` or `WRITE_CALL_LOG`), according to your question. "why didn't this happen before?" -- finding out about changes in data should imply some ability to work with the underlying data itself. Hence, I am not terribly surprised that, to register a `ContentObserver`, you need to have permissions necessary to do something with that provider.

Comment: You're right about the contacts part, I had a similar problem with contacts permissions, but that wasn't the case for this particular case. I mixed both situations up. I think I didn't analyze the bug well enough before putting it here, however, there's still unexpected crash behaviour here, and I'll elaborate the by answerring my own question. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the update to Android O. [Permissions are grouped together](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups) and since Android O [permission behaviour was changed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#rmp) because of incorrect handling of permission requests.

In my example I had added the permissions `READ_CALL_LOG`/`WRITE_CALL_LOG` and `CALL_PHONE` to the manifest, but requested only `CALL_PHONE` at first startup of the app. This caused the permission group `PHONE` to be accepted, but neither of the call-log permissions. So when the `registerContentObserver` method was called, Android implicitly accepted it to be used because of accepting the group `PHONE`.

When my user upgraded from N to O, and `registerContentObserver` was called again, it would crash (justly). Solution: check for the `READ_CALL_LOG`/`WRITE_CALL_LOG` permisions before calling `registerContentObserver`.

Workaround for users on Android O who're still using the old - crashing- code: Manually turn off & on the specific permission in the Android settings of the app (so the `PHONE` permission group in this case). This causes all permissions in this group to be accepted (or at least those permissions in that group that are required by the app)